# JLayeredPane not updating movement of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, jlayeredpane

I have a for loop that changes the location of a JLabel in a JLayeredPane layout.

```
    c.setVisible(true);
    jLayeredPane.moveToFront(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        c.setBounds(i, 500, 94, 136);
        System.out.println(c.getLocation());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

This method is referencing to jLayeredPane, which is accessed from another class. It does indeed update the *x* value of the JLabel *c*, yet it does not show it on the screen.

What do I have to do to make it update in real time? I need this to run in order, not simultaneous to the next part of the program, thus I suppose multi-threading is disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I have to do to make it update in real time?

Don't use Thread.sleep(). This will cause the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` to sleep, which means the GUI can't repaint itself until the entire loop is finished executing.

For animation you need to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

> I need this to run in order, not simultaneous to the next part of the program

When the Timer fires the required number of times you then stop the Timer and invoke a method containing the rest of your code.

Also, you should not be hardcoding "1000" as the loop control. You have no idea what the resolution of the screen will be when code is executed on different screens. You can use the `Toolkit` class and the `getScreenSize()` methods to get the appropriate dimension to use based on your actual requirement.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for your answer. I tried the Swing timer but it still doesn't update...

Comment: `I tried the Swing timer but it still doesn't update` - then your code is wrong. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So to learn the concept of a Timer, start with something simple. Just create a frame with a panel and a label on the panel. Then you add a "Start" button to the frame. When you click the button the label will move. We are not interested in your real application, only the concept you are trying to test.

Comment: @camicckr I got the Timer working, now for some reason I can't get the program to wait for the timer to finish executing before continuing.

Comment: @XHyper, yes, that is what a stated in my answer. When you start the Timer, the code following the Timer will continue to execute. That is why I stated you need to invoke a method containing the rest of the code you want to execute. So the code in your current method needs to be moved to a separate method. You need to understand that Swing programming is event oriented, which means code get executed when an event occurs. In this case the event you want to happen is started AFTER the loop is finished.